# Does this "Imaging Bed" hardware exist and what is it called?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, equipment-identification

As part of some R&D in a software development role I am trying to find a way of taking consistent images of medical instruments.

I am trying to find out if some hardware exists but I am unable to find anything by searching google but this might be because I lack the terminology to correctly search.

What I am imagining is something like the set of scales below but with perhaps a grid on the scale bed (for easy sizing) and a fixed position camera in place of the weight display.

Is this something that is available commercially and if so what would it be called?

[image: Set of scales]

Comment: Not an entire answer, but is the [photorobot](https://www.photorobot.com/how-it-works) something you're looking for? (I'm not affiliated, just found it through Google)

Comment: Not a full answer: The description of the equipment seems like it could be built using normal (pre-Google era) engineering principles. It's just a system of standard components.

Comment: @osullic A copy stand does seem to be the kind of thing I'm looking for, thanks! The photorobot looks cool but probably a bit over my needs.

Comment: Can you clarify what you need from this and how it would differ from questions such as [this one](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14648/what-is-a-good-stationary-setup-for-taking-pictures-of-small-paper-goods/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a [copy stand](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Copystands/ci/711/N/3715154809). (Link to B&H for illustrative purposes only.)

Comment: Yes! I search but couldn't remember what it was called either.

Comment: Interesting, and surprisingly expensive.  Not sure what this buys you over a sturdy tripod.

Comment: I didn't know they were that expensive! I guess the one I bought at a yard sale for $5 was quite the bargain!

Comment: @JPhi1618 note that this is 42" stand, the size usually makes for the price. The included LED system should (at that price) also ensure all areas of the stand are lit evenly, making for a larger set of leds, which also influences price

Comment: Nice and cheap on eBay